# Who did the voice of Etrec in The Mark of Archanon?

Tags: space-1999

In the Space: 1999 episode "[Mark of Archanon](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/The_Mark_of_Archanon)";

> In an attempt to appeal to the American audience, the voices of
>   Michael Gallagher (Etrec), John Alkin (Andy Johnson) and Anthony
>   Forrest (Carson) were dubbed by voice-artists speaking with American
>   accents.

Who voiced Etrec?

Answer (score 1):

The lack of a screen credit for the dubber (as well as the conjecture that several of the characters were responsible for dubbing their *own* characters due to the poor on-set sound recording) would strongly suggest that Etrec was actually over-dubbed by one of the people already credited for the episode.

I've seen some [forum chatter](http://www.space1999.net/forum/archive-t740.html) that Etrec was redubbed by [Toby Robins](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Toby_Robins) who played the character Diana Morris and also provided voice dubbing for a number of other Space : 1999 episodes.

Her accent (Canadian with a hint of English) would certainly match but short of asking the show's producers, I suspect there's no other way of confirming this.

Answer (score -1):

Sorry the earlier answer is wrong and wrong.

First - only if you are watching the UK version he actually sounds British, maybe it's different for other countries but here to me he sounds British.

Second - I think ALL the characters were responsible for dubbing their own characters, including Michael Gallagher.  This was NOT due to poor sound, but due to the fact that the characters had heavy colds (in fact you can see Michael Gallagher sneezing in a couple of scenes.) Therefore they had to dub their voices in after they got rid of the cold, so that they didn't all sound like they were all speaking through their noses.

And the final wrong part of that statement you can get the details from where I picked them up, through the directors and others information from the *Space: 1999* DVD (I think there are several Region Two versions, so I can't tell you which one it is.)

Comment: Can you offer any specific evidence to back up these bold assertions?